# VMWare Fusion Bootcamp loads wrong volume

Tags: bootcamp, vmware

I added a VM inside VMWare Fusion using the built in method for adding a bootcamp partition that runs off the actual partition rather than cloning it.

Instead of the Bootcamp VM opening Windows 10, it loads my boot manager rEFInd with no boot options available in the rEFInd menu.

I've tried

- Removing and re-adding the virtual machine :  New -> Install from Boot Camp -> Create a Boot Camp virtual machine. There was no change
- Setting the VM to use Legacy BIOS instead of EFI - VMWare could not detect an OS

When I inspect the virtual HDD attached to the bootcamp VM, it shows the volume as being over 400GB in size. I suspect this reflects the total size of the machine's built in 500GB SSD.

When my Mac is powered on it loads rEFInd with multiple options for booting including macOS, Legacy Whole Disk, and Windows Legacy. macOS boots fine, both Legacy Whole Disk and Windows Legacy options boot into the same instance of Windows 10 without any problem.

How can I load my Bootcamp partition into VMWare Fusion?

MBP 11,3 , High Sierra 10.13.6, Windows 10, VMWare Fusion 11.5.3

Comment: I would think the Boot Camp Assistant would install Windows 10 on your Mac to EFI boot. Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10? Or, did you upgrade to Windows 10 from some previous version of Windows?

Comment: @DavidAnderson There have been a few upgrades over the years but iirc Boot Camp Assistant was used to install Windows 10 under macOS Yosemite. It's possible that Windows 7 was previously on the BC partition but from recollection only using windows install media to upgrade would have broken BC driver functionality. The Boot Camp VM worked until recently when I restored from a TM backup and received an error that the disk attached to that VM cannot be opened. After the TM restore, a new VM was created in VMWare Fusion via New -> Install from Boot Camp -> Create a Boot Camp virtual machine.

Comment: I can't figure out how you ended up with rEFInd if you only installed through Boot Camp.

Comment: @Tetsujin me neither. Possibly related to the recent time machine restore? If I had to guess: it looks like the virtual machine is loading the whole disk instead of the Boot Camp partition.